# I keep getting the error unexpected token b in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

So I got this code that creates a html page.The function signup allows the user to register and create a password. The function checkpassword is to check if the correct password is entered for the username.It seems I have a problem in getting the item from local storage in my checkPassword function?Help will be much appreciated as I've been stuck for hours?

```
const PREFIX = "monash.eng1003.passwordApp.";

function checkPassword() {
  var user = document.getElementById("registerUsername").value;
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var passwordToCheck = localStorage.getItem(PREFIX + user);
  var passwordTwo = JSON.parse(passwordToCheck);

  if (password != passwordTwo) {
    alert("Don't hack" + user);
  } else {
    alert("Welcome" + user);
  }
}

function signup() {
  var user = document.getElementById("registerUsername").value;
  var pass1 = document.getElementById("registerPassword").value;
  var pass2 = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
  if ((pass1 === pass2) && (pass1 !== "")) {
    if (localStorage) {
      var passwordToStore = pass1;

      localStorage.setItem(PREFIX + user, passwordToStore);
      alert("Account created for username: " + user);
    }
  } else {
    alert("Passwords must match and cannot be empty.")
  }
}
```

EDIT:Thanks for pointing out that I do not need to parse it since I didn't stringify.That solved the problem but since I cannot delete the post I have to leave it here

Comment: Apparently there is a problem with parsing the JSON that you didn't share. Check what `passwordToCheck` is. If you spot an obious error, delete the question. If you think it's valid JSON, anonymize it and edit it into your question.

Comment: You're not using `JSON.stringify` when storing the item in localStorage, why are you using `JSON.parse` when retrieving it?

Comment: Without the actual JSON, it is impossible to identify you issue

Comment: Well what is `passwordToCheck`

Comment: And why are you using localstorage for passwords... I am guessing you know it is not secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't convert the password to JSON when you stored it, so you don't need to use `JSON.parse()` when you retrieve it. You stored an ordinary string, you can just retrieve it and use it.

```
passwordTwo = localStorage.getItem(PREFIX + user);
```